# What to check if Jboss instance on server behaves differently than the same instance locally?

Tags: java, soap, jboss

I have a Java SOAP Web Service which follows a pretty standard architecture:

[image]

The SOAP client contacts the WebService running on the Jboss instance (whether it's running locally or remotely), the WebService invokes (in RMI) the remote application, which responds with some data and returns them to the requester.

My issue is pretty much the following:

- On the Jboss local instance, the response is correctly returned to the SOAP client, something like this:

  ```
  <soap:Envelope>
      <soap:Body>
          <myResponse>
              [ELEMENTS OF MY RESPONSE]
          </myResponse>
      </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
  ```
- On the Jboss remote instance, rhe response is returned **empty** to the SOAP client, even though any error is raised neither on server side nor on Jboss instance:

  ```
  <soap:Envelope>
      <soap:Body>
          <myResponse>
              EMPTY IN HERE
          </myResponse>
      </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
  ```

Since it works on the local instance, I've not many ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue. This is what I've tried so far:

- I've tried to fully recompile the `.war` that is deployed on the remote instance - which is exactly the same used in the local instance.
- I've tried to decompile the `.war` in the remote instance and check the `wsdl` / `xsd` files defined for the requests and responses: they are correct (and equal to the ones in the local instance, for what it matters).
- I've also tried to attach a remote debugger on the Application server, in order to check if the response was correctly prepared when called by the remote Jboss instance: the response is correct on server side.
- I've also tried to run another request (different than the one in question) on the remote Jboss server, and the response is correctly returned.
- I have tried to compare the `standalone-full.xml` (configuration file) of both local and remote instance, and the only difference I can see is a socket binding for remoting in the remote version that I don't have in the local version:

  ```
  <socket-binding name="remoting" port="1013"/>
  ```
- Finally, I have attached a remote debugger to my Jboss remote instance and checked what happen in the WebService itself. The input and the output are well prepared:

  ```
  @WebMethod
  @WebResult(name = "ProductEvaluation")
  public ProductEvaluations myAPIRequest(@WebParam(name = "XmlProducts") final XmlProducts xmlProducts,
      @WebParam(name = "ConnectedToRealtime") final boolean connectedToRealtime,
      @WebParam(name = "Timeout") final Timeout timeout) throws ProductEvaluationFault, TimeoutFault, ProductConfigurationFault, SecurityFault {
      try {
          // some stuff here...
          return result; //result contains what I want
      } catch (SecurityException e) {
          throw new SecurityFault(e.getMessage());
      }
  }
  ```

  Everything coming earlier in the stack is generic:

  ```
  NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 62  
  DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
  Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 498  
  ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 52    
  InterceptorContext.proceed() line: 340  
  ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 45 
  InterceptorContext.proceed() line: 340  
  InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 21   
  InterceptorContext.proceed() line: 340  
  ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 61   
  ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 52   
  InterceptorContext.proceed() line: 340  
  WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 56    
  InterceptorContext.proceed() line: 340  
  InterceptorContext.run() line: 356  
  WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: 636    
  AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 61    
  InterceptorContext.proceed() line: 340  
  InterceptorContext.run() line: 356  
  PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 80    
  InterceptorContext.proceed() line: 340  
  ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(InterceptorContext) line: 61   
  ViewService$View.invoke(InterceptorContext) line: 195   
  InvocationHandlerJAXWS(AbstractInvocationHandler).invoke(Endpoint, Invocation) line: 137    
  JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(Exchange, Object, Method, Object[]) line: 169  
  JBossWSInvoker(AbstractInvoker).invoke(Exchange, Object, Method, List<Object>) line: 96 
  JBossWSInvoker(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker).invoke(Exchange, Object, Method, List<Object>) line: 232 
  JBossWSInvoker(JAXWSMethodInvoker).invoke(Exchange, Object, Method, List<Object>) line: 85  
  JBossWSInvoker.invoke(Exchange, Object) line: 145   
  ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run() line: 59  
  Executors$RunnableAdapter<T>.call() line: 511   
  ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2(FutureTask<V>).run() line: 266  
  ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run() line: 126 
  SynchronousExecutor.execute(Runnable) line: 37  
  ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(Message) line: 131  
  PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(Message) line: 308    
  ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(Message) line: 121    
  ServletDestination(AbstractHTTPDestination).invoke(ServletConfig, ServletContext, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 251    
  RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(Endpoint, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServletContext) line: 108   
  ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServletContext, Bus, Endpoint) line: 134  
  CXFServletExt.invoke(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 88  
  CXFServletExt(AbstractHTTPServlet).handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 293 
  CXFServletExt(AbstractHTTPServlet).doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 212    
  CXFServletExt(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 707   
  CXFServletExt.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServletContext) line: 136    
  WSFServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 140   
  WSFServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 790  
  ServletHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 85   
  ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 62   
  ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 36    
  SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 78    
  PredicateHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 43 
  SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 131    
  ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 57 
  PredicateHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 43 
  ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler(AbstractConfidentialityHandler).handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 46  
  ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 64  
  AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 60  
  CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 77    
  NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 50  
  SecurityInitialHandler(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler).handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 43    
  PredicateHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 43 
  JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 61 
  PredicateHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 43 
  PredicateHandler.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 43 
  ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(HttpServerExchange, ServletChain, ServletRequestContext, ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 285    
  ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(HttpServerExchange, ServletRequestContext, ServletChain, DispatcherType) line: 264    
  ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler, HttpServerExchange, ServletRequestContext, ServletChain, DispatcherType) line: 81   
  ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(HttpServerExchange) line: 175 
  Connectors.executeRootHandler(HttpHandler, HttpServerExchange) line: 202    
  HttpServerExchange$1.run() line: 792    
  XnioWorker$TaskPool(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1142 
  ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617   
  Thread.run() line: 748
  ```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can debug this sort of issue? Any configuration file I'm forgetting to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours struggling, I finally figured out what was wrong myself.

Although it may seem a simple typo, it made me lose a lot of time and shows an interesting behavioral difference between the remote and the local instances of Jboss, so I'm posting an answer to spare some time to someone falling in the same mistake.

The new `@WebMethod` that I developed was this one:

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "ProductEvaluation")
public ProductEvaluations myAPIRequest(@WebParam(name = "XmlProducts") final XmlProducts xmlProducts,
    @WebParam(name = "ConnectedToRealtime") final boolean connectedToRealtime,
    @WebParam(name = "Timeout") final Timeout timeout) throws ProductEvaluationFault, TimeoutFault, ProductConfigurationFault, SecurityFault {
    try {
        // some stuff here...
        return result; //result contains what I want
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        throw new SecurityFault(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As you may notice (I actually took 4 hours to notice it, so maybe it's not that visible):

- The return type of the function is `ProductEvaluations` (meaning a list of `ProductEvaluation`), and that's what is specified as well in the `wsdl` and the `xsd`
- However, I forgot the `s` on the annotation just above `@WebResult(name="ProductEvaluation")`

As of my experience, hence, I have noticed that:

- When Jboss runs locally, the annotation `@WebResult` is ignored and the result is returned in any case.
- However, when Jboss runs remotely, this mapping is done. Hence, since I was returning `ProductEvaluations` (with an `s`) but saying the `@WebResult` was a `ProductEvaluation` (without an `s`), then the remote server wasn't mapping anything and the response was coming empty.